# Upgrading ruby to 2.3.4 with rails 3.0.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-2.3

I am trying to upgrade my rails 3.0.5 application with ruby 2.3.4. Originally it was ruby 1.9.3. I was able to fix most things by updating the gems. However, i m stuck on this one problem where when creating new active record objects, the time does not convert properly.

For example

`Product.new(:bought_on => Date.today)` will save the object with `bought_on` to be the date, not datetime.

I was able to narrow down the problem to the file

> activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb

For some reason its not calling these two functions, `define_method_attribute` and `define_method_attribute=`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime.now` instead? `Date.today` will never have time because it is simply a `Date`. Also any reason you are updating `ruby` but leaving `rails` at `3.0`  (circa 2010)?

Comment: @engineersmnky, thanks for replying. Upgrading rails from `3.0` to `4` would be alot of refactoring, I am being optimistic that only upgrading ruby to `2` would work.

Comment: I found the issue, the `define_method_attribute` under `time_zone_conversion.rb` is a protected method, and in ruby 2, the `respond_to` function always returns false for protected methods. Had to monkey patch to remove the protected attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the `define_method_attribute` under `time_zone_conversion.rb` is a protected method, and in ruby 2, the respond_to function always returns false for protected methods. Had to monkey patch to remove the protected attribute.